# Install AnyDesk in Ubuntu Server Raspberry PI 4 image via Terminal

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, sudo, wget

I've been struggling to install AnyDesk in a flashed Ubuntu Server 20.04 image for Raspberry PI 4.

What I've done is the following:

1. delete and clear all other previous installations:

   sudo apt-get purge anydesk

   sudo apt-get autoclean

   sudo apt-get autoremove
2. Adding armhf arquitechture (after step 1 some things must be reinstalled again):

   sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf

   sudo apt-get update

   sudo apt-get install crossbuild-essential-armhf
3. Install AnyDesk from .deb file:

   wget http://deb.anydesk.com/pool/main/a/anydesk/anydesk_6.0.1_armhf.deb

   sudo dpkg -i anydesk_6.0.1_armhf.deb

   sudo apt install ./anydesk_6.0.1_armhf.deb

When I run the last command line of step 3, I get a message saying that anydesk:armhf will be installed instead of anydesk_6.0.1_armhf.deb, afterwards, a report with metrics for installed, updated, and uninstalled packages appears saying 0 for all of them, saying anydesk is already installed to its last version.

So I try to run "anydesk" from the Terminal and nothing else comes up. I would try to do so directly within the PI's desktop, and not through terminal, but I'm working remotely and that's not a possibility at the moment.

How could I solve this?

Thanks in advance for any valuable input.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
```

after

```
sudo dpkg -i anydesk_6.0.1_armhf.deb
```

I just tried your ways and it worked like a charm.

I am using `anydesk_6.1.1_armhf.deb`.

Answer (score 0):

at step 3, cd into where you downloaded anydesk deb file, and use:
`sudo gdebi anydesk_6.0.1-1_armhf.deb` (6.0.1-1 is the actual last version available)

gdebi will solve all the dependencies missing for you.
if you don't have it, just run: `sudo apt install gdebi`

Answer (score 0):

Just a small update - crucial fact - for everyone like me trying to install AnyDesk on RPi 4 with x64 OS (Ubuntu, Raspbian, doesn't matter) it won't work as AnyDesk only supports x32 OS.

More details/discussion can be found [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/Raspberry-Pi-OS-64bit/issues/82).

Answer (score 0):

## To install Anydesk on your raspberry pi,copy and paste below commands one by one after each completion:

1. sudo apt update
2. sudo apt full-upgrade
3. wget https://download.anydesk.com/rpi/anydesk_6.1.1-1_armhf.deb
4. sudo dpkg -i anydesk_6.1.1-1_armhf.deb
5. sudo apt-get install -f

Done you can check Anydesk is installed on your raspberry pi.