# Problem installing Anydesk on Ubuntu 21.04 installed on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: command-line, system-installation, software-installation, shortcut-keys, anydesk

My problem is continuing since last few days, to start with, I had downloaded the latest arm version of Anydesk from the website which I believe is 6.1.1, I tried to installed the same through terminal and as well as through Ubuntu software installer, many iterations were been tried Everytime I could see an anydesk icon on show application list but when I tried to open it I can't, it simply failed to open up,
Infact on the contrary I could see the software in show application list but the same after installation, I can't see under installed list of app where in other application installed are seen
It would be highly appreciated, if you can share the full details of how to get it installed on my Ubuntu desktop so that I can able to proceed it

Also, please do let me know the process of full uninstallation of the same as well as based on your reply first I shall be uninstalling what's so ever been installed fully and as a fresh I shall take it further
Considering that I am new to Ubuntu, there are fair possibilities that some thing I might have missed out or due to jeopardy some thing might be conflicting with the other
Appreciate your guidance on the way forward

Comment: check in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274729/install-anydesk-in-ubuntu-server-raspberry-pi-4-image-via-terminal/1356646#1356646), also check my answer there, hope it helps

Comment: I did the same as well and infact the post had helped me out a lot but the only thing I could see is that I can see the icon on my screen but i can't open it though
I think some where in installation some thing is missing or some where some thing is not be installed or I can't figure it out what's going wrong

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a issue with 21.10 too. Before upgrading Anydesk was working well on 20.04.

One thing I was able to resolve was sharing screen issue on 21.10 (google meet sharing was showing blank screen) by configuring XORG (Thought this was related, but still didnt work)

Here is the link you can try

https://fostips.com/switch-back-xorg-ubuntu-21-04/

Installing libpangox-1.0-0 worked

sudo apt install libpangox-1.0-0

Comment: It is not working in 21.04 and 21.10

Comment: Here is a fix for 21.10 - https://askubuntu.com/a/1371523/103478

Comment: sudo apt install libpangox-1.0-0 Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

run from terminal as regular user, it will tell you what's wrong, something about policy, and also anydesk needs monitor to run, i don't know why, i plugged my monitor then it works