# Anydesk is not working after upgrading to 21.10

Tags: anydesk

I have upgraded Ubuntu from version 21.04 to 21.10. But after the upgrade, Anydesk is not opening. Another screen-sharing app like TeamViewer is working. I tried Xorg also, but no progress.
Please suggest a working solution.

Comment: Can you open the software from terminal, and post the output by editing the question?

Answer (score 33):

`sudo apt install libpangox-1.0-0`

fixed it for me.

Comment: For anyone who is getting ```no package found error```: Install [multiarch-support_2.28-10_amd64.deb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/multiarch-support/download) first then install [libpangox-1.0-0_0.0.2-5_amd64.deb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libpangox-1.0-0/download)

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing a Error : such as remote not supported or something like that the same thing could be fixed by disabling wayland `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and find
`WaylandEnable=true` to `WaylandEnable=false` it might help you

Comment: even after setup WaylandEnable=false does not work for you, just restart your machine and everything should works